# saving list of tables in xlsx file

Tags: r

I have many functions which create a list of tables. All the tables have different demographies.

I am looking for a something which dynamically save the list of tables in xlsx file one by one.

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)

df <- mtcars[1:7,]

df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
banner <- c("T1","T2","T3")


t1 <- df1
t2 <- df2
t3 <- df3

t1 <- t1 %>%
      add_row() %>%
      mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))
    
t2 <- t2 %>%
  add_row() %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))

t3 <- t3 %>%
  add_row() %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))

table_list1 <- list(t1,t2,t3)
  names(table_list1) <- banner
  Map(cbind, table_list1, SampleID = names(table_list1))
  
  
  colnames <- c("name","TT1","TT2", "TT3","TT4","TT5","TT6","TT7","TT8","TT9","TT10") 
  
  for (i in seq_along(table_list1)){
    colnames(table_list1[[i]]) <- colnames
  }
  
  t2 <- do.call(rbind,table_list1)
  t2

tbl1 <- t2  
tbl2 = mtcars %>% 
  cross_cpct(
    cell_vars = list(cyl, gear),
    col_vars = list(total(), am, vs)
  ) %>% 
  set_caption("Table 1")

# above this is everything is ok as required

tbls <- list(tbl1,tbl2)
startRows <- c(0, cumsum(2 + sapply(tbls, nrow)[-length(tbls)])) + 1

#fn <- tempfile(fileext = "xlsx")

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
mapply(function(tbl, startRow) writeData(wb, "sheet1", x = tbl, startRow = startRow), tbls, startRows)

saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I have tried this way but it its not showing t1.1, t1.2,t1.3 in xlsx file. Is there a solution for this?

actually its not saving tables in xlsx files also not showing the labels for t2 (Total, Transmission,engine) in separate row, i am getting many errors meanwhile trying this approach

it should save tables in xlsx files like below

[image]

Comment: Can you please shorten the code so that it only contains the relevant parts for the problem? Namely th input data and the code referring to saving it in Excel. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @deschen i have the question

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @deschen I mean i have updated the question

Comment: does the solution below solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heavily reduced your "example" to what is needed for your problem.

Use `map2` from package `purrr` to loop over your tables list and the startrows vector at the same time.

```
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)

tbl1 <- mtcars[1:3, ]
tbl2 <- mtcars[4:6, ]

tbls <- list(tbl1,tbl2)
startRows <- c(0, cumsum(2 + sapply(tbls, nrow)[-length(tbls)])) + 1

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")

map2(.x = tbls,
     .y = startRows,
     .f = ~writeData(wb       = wb,
                     sheet    = "sheet1",
                     x        = .x,
                     startRow = .y))

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Proof of created Excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are no "t1.1, t1.2,t1.3" tables in your list with tables "tbls".

If it is ok then there is a special function in the expss for saving list of tables in xlsx:

```
expss::xl_write_file(tbls, filename = "test.xlsx", sheet = "sheet1")
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not giving the expected required output